# Argument Labels in C#

Tags: c#

Is there a way in C# to be able to refer to a a parameter by both an internal and external name (in Swift this is known as argument labels/parameters)?

What I mean is suppose I have the following:

```
public static class Sport
{
    public static void Print(int id sportID)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(sportID);
    }
}

public static void main()
{
    Sport.Print(id: 123);
}
```

Internally, I refer to the id as sportID, but externally, the parameter is known as id.

Comment: No.  Why would you want to do this?

Comment: No, but you could just create a new variable `sportID = id` on the first line.

Comment: You can write another method that delegates to the first, and alias the variable however you want.

Comment: @Amy presumably because Objective-C (kinda sorta) and some other languages have it. It can be occasionally be useful.

Comment: Yes, in Swift this is known as argument labels and parameter names. Here's an explanation of why a developer would do this:  "The use of argument labels can allow a function to be called in an expressive, sentence-like manner, while still providing a function body that is readable and clear in intent."

 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Comment: I'm curious when exactly this would be useful. Seems a bit like something is off if you really need the parameter name when the function is called to be different that in the body of the function and seems potentially really confusing. What would happen if you declared another local function called `id` in the body of your function?

Comment: Matt, I see what you mean. Here's a link to a Stanford iOS lecture where Paul explains a good scenario for argument labeling. Fast forward to 1:07:20 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcxp1bbXbL4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void Print(int id)
{
    int sportId = id;
    Console.Out.WriteLine(sportID);
}
```

?

There's no language implicit way of aliasing the var that I'm aware of, but you can rename it by passing it to another, private function that calls it `sportId`, or you can assign it to a new var yourself in the function.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the game, but I was looking for something like this as well. It is not exactly what the OP is after, but I think it is close enough.

The parameter names that are set when you declare the methods can be called when calling the method.

Declaring the method:

```
   static string[] Roster(int numberOfDaysOff, int daysOfStartOnDay) {
      // Method logic with the set names
   }
```

Calling the method:

```
Roster(numberOfDaysOff: daysOff,daysOfStartOnDay: startDay);
```

Hope this helps future readers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you'd want to do this but here is one way:

```
class Parameters
{
    private int _id;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id;}
        set { _id = value;}
    }
    public int SportID
    {
        get { return _id;}
        set { _id = value;}
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm so happy to see this syntax in C#, but I don't think this relates to the question